# Django Rest Framework - Serializing Many To Many fields attributes to POST operation

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following model

```
class Metrics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Nombre'
    )
    value = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits = 5,
        decimal_places = 3,
        verbose_name = 'Valor',
        null = True,
        blank = True
    )
```

And in another model I have the `ManyToManyField` relationship to the `Metrics` model

```
class PatientMonitoring(models.Model):
    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metrics, verbose_name='Métricas', 

)
```

My `serializers.py` file look of this way:

```
class MetricsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Metrics
        fields = ('name','value',)

class PatientMonitoringSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    metrics = MetricsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PatientMonitoring
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'metrics')
        #depth=2

    def create(self,validated_data):
        metrics_data = validated_data.pop('metrics')
        metric = Metrics.object.create(**validated_data)
        for metric_data in metrics_data:
            Metrics.objects.create(metric=metric,**metrics_data)
        metric.save()
        return metric
```

The result are that my models are being serialized, but they dont `have POST permissions and the form view, is not being update or create

[image]

I am defining the create method, [which is described](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) here for work with models serialized and write/post operations, but I don't understand how the process is doing all this functionality.
How to can I work with my model and attribute with POST methods in a case like this?

***UPDATE**

I've performed a `POST` operation via `curl` such as @RossRogers and @Nirri suggest me and the behavior is the following:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/patientmonitoring/ -d "metrics=Grados"
```

And I get this message in relation to my `create` method

```
File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrhb_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 191, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/neurorehabilitation-project/patient_monitoring/serializers.py", line 37, in create
    metric = Metrics.object.create(**validated_data)
AttributeError: type object 'Metrics' has no attribute 'object'
[28/Jun/2016 17:19:16] "POST /api/patientmonitoring/ HTTP/1.1" 500 104669
```

Comment: [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)  json directly?

Comment: @RossRogers You mean to if my JSON expose model can be consumed via curl directly? In affirmative case:  ```curl http://localhost:8000/api/patientmonitoring/6/
{"url":"http://localhost:8000/api/patientmonitoring/6/","id":6,"metrics":[{"name":"Grados","value":null},{"name":"Grados","value":null},{"name":"Grados","value":null}]}% ```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it says, lists are not supported in HTML input.

As you can see here (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.2-announcement/), it was planned for 3.3 release but there's no mention of it in the release notes.

It doesn't mean you don't have permissions to do POST requests. Try making a POST request with raw JSON (as suggested in a comment on your post) with DHC, Postman or even curl.

Comment: I don't see any mention of a StringRelatedField in your original post's code. Although this question might be of some help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936401/string-related-field-in-djangorest

Comment: It's true, `StringRelatedField` is not suited, my apologies for the previous comment/question. I've updated my original question in relation to my current problem in case of that you can support me. 

Comment: It's objects, not object. You have a typo.